# Why using AJAX File Upload if PHP already sends the file?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Here there's a tutorial about AJAX file upload : 
https://phpacademy.org/course/javascript-ajax-file-upload-with-progress-indicator
"A JavaScript AJAX file uploader that handles multiple file upload and percentage progress indicator. Uses PHP to handle file uploading."

What's the purpose of doing all this javascript with FormData and XMLHttpRequest to send the files?
I'm sorry, I just don't get it.
It's PHP that sends the file. What's uploaded by AJAX ?

Patrick

Comment: `It's PHP that sends the file`  Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: PHP doesn't do anything to send a file to the webserver, it only runs on the webserver accepting files sent to that webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the advantages of using AJAX in your life is that you send stuff to the server without making the browser loading a new page. With that AJAX file uploader, you send files to the server but you are always on the same page. With FormData you can do things like showing a progress bar of the upload.

Comment: Thanks. But what people were using before the advent of the FormData object ?

Comment: Before FormData, Flash-based libraries were used to upload files this way.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the purpose of doing all this javascript with FormData and XMLHttpRequest to send the files?

So you can do it without leaving the page

> It's PHP that sends the file.

No, PHP **receives** the file.